# For loop returns only last variable values in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for loop to fill an empty matrix that I want to convert in a dataframe later on. As shown below, I want to aggregate my monthly data in quarterly and repeat this operation for 15 variables. However, whenever I run this loop I only get the aggregate values of the last variable (15th), but not for the previous 14

My code is the following:

```
a=names(monthly)
data_ts = matrix(ncol=15, nrow=160)

for (i in 2:16){
data_ts <- ts(monthly[[a[i]]], start=c(1982,1), frequency=12)
data_ts <- aggregate.ts(data_ts, nfrequency=4)/3
data_ts <- as.data.frame(data_ts)
colnames(data_ts) <- c(a[i])
}
```

How can I fix it? The colname of the 15th variable is okay, the only problem is to get the values for the previous 14.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would think by looking at this code you're over-writing the value each time. The reason why you get the 15th occurrence is because that's when the loop ends. If you were to stop it when i = 6, for example, you'd have the 5th occurrence.

What you need to do is either:

1. Append/concat the data to make a new df and then add this df to your existing df.
2. Make new columns for each occurrence, and ensure they have the occurrences from 2 to 16.